# Flatpak applications borked under NixOS

Tags: gnome, nixos, flatpak

I just migrated from `Arch Linux` to `NixOS`. I configured the system to install `GNOME`. I'm used to install desktop applications using Flatpak, so I went ahead and configured everything...just to realize almost all Flatpak applications are *borked* and are unable to display the correct theme, fonts, and icons. This is a major issue (at least for me) because sometimes it's impossible to know where the cursor is located at in the screen, the usual interface (not application-specific) icons are changed for the most part, so they don't change accordingly — for instance, when trying to resize windows the cursor doesn't change to give you the proper hint.

I researched the subject and looks like there are issues reported for this, but I wonder if someone has found a solution — hopefully that doesn't involve modifying too much the system.

I did install the fonts in the recommended way, but nothing changed:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports = [
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
  ];
  ...
  fonts = {
    enableDefaultFonts = true;
    fontDir.enable = true;
    fontconfig = {
      antialias = true;
      cache32Bit = true;
      hinting.autohint = true;
      hinting.enable = true;
    };
    fonts = with pkgs; [
      noto-fonts
      noto-fonts-cjk
      noto-fonts-emoji
      # noto-fonts-extra # Was present in Arch Linux :/
      ubuntu_font_family
    ];
  };
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (or was) a known issue for people running `Flatpak` applications in `NixOS`.

Took a while, but [there is already a fix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/262462) for it, so once the changes are merged and released, this won't be an issue anymore